# How can I validate the initial and end date using AngularJS, JavaScript and Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker

I'm currently involved in a project where we are using Angular, JavaScript and C#. In this project, we have a form for creating projects with the fields: project code, description, initial date, end date, client, technology and amount per hour.

For the inputs "initial date" and "end date" I'm using a datepicker in order to provide a calendar to the users where they can choose the desired date. The problem I'm dealing with is the validation for the "end date". So far I got the weekends and days before the current date disabled in the calendar.

My idea is to disable the previous days to the initial  selected date in the calendar of the "final date" so it can't be smaller than the "initial date".

JavaScript and HTML code:

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('app.project')
    .controller('projectCreateCtrl', ['$state', 'alerts', 'project', projectCreateCtrl])
    .controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', ['$scope', DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl]);

  //Controller for the initial and end date
  function DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.vm.project.fechaInicio = new Date();
      $scope.vm.project.fechaFin = new Date();

    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.inlineOptions = {
      customClass: getDayClass,
      minDate: new Date(),
      showWeeks: true
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
      dateDisabled: disabled,
      formatYear: 'yy',
      maxDate: new Date(2050, 1, 1),
      minDate: new Date(),
      startingDay: 1
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    function disabled(data) {
      var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
      return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    }

    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
      $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();



    $scope.open1 = function() {
      $scope.popup1.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.open2 = function() {
      $scope.popup2.opened = true;
    };


    $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
      $scope.vm.project.fechaInicio = new Date(year, month, day);
      $scope.vm.project.fechaFin = new Date(year, month, day);
    };

    //Date format
    $scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';

    $scope.popup1 = {
      opened: false
    };

    $scope.popup2 = {
      opened: false
    };

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date();
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    $scope.events = [{
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    }, {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }];

    function getDayClass(data) {
      var date = data.date,
        mode = data.mode;
      if (mode === 'day') {
        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
          var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

          if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
            return $scope.events[i].status;
          }
        }
      }

      return '';
    }

   
  }

  //Form controller
  function projectCreateCtrl($state, alerts, project) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.project = project;

    //Warning about the new project being saved
    vm.insert = function() {
      alerts.confirmSave('', 'Se guardará el proyecto \n¿Está seguro?', vm.save);
    }

    //Back button
    vm.volver = function() {
      $state.go("app.project.index")
    }

    //saves project
    vm.save = function() {
      //projectService.saveProject(vm.project)
      project.$save(
        function() { //OK
          alerts.success("Se ha guardado el proyecto correctamente.", '', function() {

          });
        },
        function(error) { //ERROR
          alerts.error(error);
        });
    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
  <div class="form-group row m-t">
    <label for="fechaInicio" class="col-md-1 control-label">Fecha Inicio</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="has-feedback" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (form.fechaInicio.$dirty || form.fechaInicio.$touched) && form.fechaInicio.$invalid, 'has-success':form.fechaInicio.$valid}">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-class="{ 'form-control input': form.fechaInicio.$valid, 'form-control input mandatory': !form.fechaInicio.$valid  }" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" readonly ng-model="vm.project.fechaInicio"
          is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" min-date="minDate" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
        </p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="form.fechaInicio.$valid" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="!form.fechaInicio.$valid && form.fechaInicio.$dirty" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.fechaInicio.$error" ng-show="form.fechaInicio.$dirty || form.fechaInicio.$touched">
          <div ng-messages-include="wwwroot/app/project/messages.html"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group row m-t">
    <label for="fechaFin" class="col-md-1 control-label">Fecha Fin</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="has-feedback" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (form.fechaFin.$dirty || form.fechaFin.$touched) && form.fechaFin.$invalid, 'has-success':form.fechaFin.$valid}">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-class="{ 'form-control input': form.fechaFin.$valid, 'form-control input mandatory': !form.fechaFin.$valid  }" id="fechaFin" name="fechaFin" readonly data-min-date="fechaInicio" ng-model="vm.project.fechaFin"
          is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
        </p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="form.fechaFin.$valid" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" ng-show="!form.fechaFin.$valid && form.fechaFin.$dirty" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.fechaFin.$error" ng-show="form.fechaFin.$dirty || form.fechaFin.$touched">
          <div ng-messages-include="wwwroot/app/project/messages.html"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Translations needed:

fechaInicio = initial date

fechaFin = end date

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You already used `minDate` option to disable days on calendar from now, you could just have another `$scope.dateOptions` for `fechaFin`  where `minDate` is `vm.project.fechaInicio`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've already tried that but for some reason I still able to choose a final date previous to the initial date selected in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right, you want to get date from initial date Datepicker and then give user to choose end date after that date. 
Then just save selected date from "initial date Datepicker" in scope and then pass it as "startDate" in options of "end date Datepicker".
Read datepicker docs from better understanding [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html)

hope this has solved your issue

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will have a look to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.

For this you need to create two dateOptions in your controller. i.e.

```
$scope.fromOptions = {
  dateDisabled: disabled,
  formatYear: 'yy',
  maxDate: new Date(2050, 1, 1),
  minDate: new Date(),
  startingDay: 1
};

$scope.tillOptions = {
  dateDisabled: disabled,
  formatYear: 'yy',
  maxDate: new Date(2050, 1, 1),
  minDate: $scope.project.fechaInicio, // use from scope value here.
  startingDay: 1
};
```

and use these datepicker options in their datepicker-options respectively.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've done that but for some reason I still able to choose a final date previous to the initial date selected. I have added the new options for the end date in the JavaScript file and the datepicker-options="tillOptions" in the HTML end date input.